# How to make a context menu in a custom ckeditor5 widget?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I made a inline widget similar a placeholder (ckeditor4), but now I want to render a dropdown when the widget is selected to show options values to replace the placeholder. I trying use **BalloonPanelView** but no success until now, someone have a idea about how to make it?

```
this.editor.editing.view.document.on('click', (evt, data) => {
    evt.stop();
    const element = data.target;
    if (element && element.hasClass('placeholder')) {
        if (!element.getAttribute('data-is-fixed')) {
            const balloonPanelView = new BalloonPanelView();
            balloonPanelView.render();
            ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'].forEach((value) => {
                const view = new View();
                view.set({
                    label: value,
                    withText: true
                });
                balloonPanelView.content.add(view);
            });
            balloonPanelView.pin({
                target: element
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hello @Tiago i'am facing the same issue, have you finally found a solution ? Kind regards

Comment: I posted a resume of solution for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using ContextualBalloon class:

```
import ContextualBalloon from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/panel/balloon/contextualballoon";

// Define ballon
const balloon = editor.plugins.get(ContextualBalloon);

const placeholderOptions = // Here I defined list with buttons '<li><button></li>' 

// Finnaly render ballon
balloon.add({
    view: placeholderOptions,
    singleViewMode: true,
    position: {
         target: data.domTarget
    }
});
```

Comment: What sort of context was this added in?  Is this within a "UI" plugin class?  Something else?  I would be very grateful if a more holistic snippet, with surrounding context, could be added.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello @LukeA.Leber, i was need make a text mask with some variables and options defined to select, so a implemented a placeholder element. I needed add a dropdown on toolbar to select variables to add in some place of text content too.
The user select some mask to add on ckeditor content and after that click on placeholder and choose the option to complete the content.